# How to save changes made to text file after opening it as a File?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text file in memory that I open using File.readAsString().. This extracts the text from it and saves it as a String. This is given to a TextField() so that changes can be made to this text.

How do I effectively save these changes back to the original file?

Here is my code so far. Everything works as is, the file opens and the text in it is displayed in the TextField. But I dont know how to save the changes back to file..

```
class _NoteEditScreenState extends State<NoteEditScreen> {

  TextEditingController _controller;

  String startingText = '';
  String fileName;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getTextFromFile().whenComplete(() {
      //when we read the string, extract lines from it
      lines = lineSplitter.convert(startingText);
      setState(() {
        _controller = TextEditingController(text: startingText);
      });

    });
    fileName = widget.txtPath.split('/').last;


  }


  Future getTextFromFile() async {
    final file = File(widget.txtPath);
    //read the file
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    startingText = contents;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(fileName),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: (){
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: TextSearch(lines));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            //height: 50.0,
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The way I see it happening is to delete the old file and create a new file with same name.. Is this the best way of doing this? Or can you guys suggest a better way?

Comment: There are definitely better ways than what you suggest. I suggest your look at the `File` class [documentaiton](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/File-class.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a file, you can use

`yourFile.writeAsString(contents)` or     `yourFile.writeAsStringSync(contents)`.

Use `writeAsString` if you don't want to wait for the file to write completely or if you don't want to block app execution, **or** use `writeAsStringSync` if you want to prevent the app from continuing until it's done writing.

[Docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/File/writeAsString.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know about ``writeAsString()`` but my question is to save changes to the same file from which the text has been read. Will calling ``writeAsString()`` overwrite the same file?

Comment: Yes. You're calling it on that file. This doesn't append data, it overwrites. So ideally, you'll load the file into memory, edit the contents and then write the new string to the file, replacing the old contents.
The problem is that you created the file within the read method. Try creating the file in a higher scope and pass it to the methods so that you're accessing the same file, rather than opening it to read, and then opening it to write.

The correct way to do this, though, is to not process this within the widget. Widgets are for displaying data to the user, not for processing data.

Comment: Overwriting depends on the `FileMode`. By default, it will overwrite, but you can easily append data by changing the `FileMode` to `FileMode.append`.